# Bad Image error when opening SCVMM Admin Console

Tags: scvmm

I have recently installed SCVMM onto a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard box following [the instructions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380687.aspx).

This is being installed using a virtual ISO emulator rather than a DVD.  The initial System Center Virtual Machine Manager installation did fail due to WAIK needing to be installed separately.  WAIK was installed and the installation completed.  However, when attempting to open the VMM Administrator Console the application crashes with the following message:

> VmmAdmin.exe - Bad Image
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2\bin\VMRCActiveXClient.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.

A quick Google search has suggested that this could be because the WAIK doesn't like to be installed from an ISO emulator.  I've written the ISO to DVD and re installed, but the issue is still there.

Any idea what else could be causing this issue?